# What is a good software package to create a FAQ site?

Tags: package

I am looking for a faq software package that would allow me to create a Q&A site. I looked at some of the similar questions but I didn't find anything suitable. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My wishlist:

- Prefer a non-wiki solution
- Windows/.NET solution would be ideal but not required
- Doesn't matter if solution is commercial/open source
- Ability to sort questions by category/topic/tags
- Support for embedding images within text
- Option to rate answers
- RSS Feed, if possible
- Ability to assign related questions

Something like this http://kb.mediatemple.net/ would be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You say commercial/open source doesn't matter. Does it matter if it's a hosted service? If hosted is OK, you could try [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), which runs the same software that Stack Overflow runs on. It's more of a Q&A site than a FAQ site, but you could probably add links to the most common questions in the sidebar, and use search for finding anything else.

- Prefer a non-wiki solution ✓
- Windows/.NET solution would be ideal but not required ✓
- Doesn't matter if solution is commercial/open source ✓
- Ability to sort questions by category/topic/tags ✓
- Support for embedding images within text ✓
- Option to rate answers ✓
- RSS Feed, if possible ✓
- Ability to assign related questions ✗

Comment: I've looked into StackExchange and it would be a good solution but the price tag is bit of an issue. But it has a lot of the functionality that I am looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

The site you posted, I think runs on [interspire](http://www.interspire.com/support/kb/)

I also agree w/[brian campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031553/what-is-a-good-software-package-to-create-a-faq-site/2031587#2031587), [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) is excellent too.

Comment: Thank You for providing the link to interspire. Their product looks interesting. Will look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to read the best practices for knowledge management and knowledge sharing at http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/best-practices.php

We use their knowledge management product and found this information on their website while doing research about their software.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and my google-fu lead me to [phpMyFAQ](http://www.phpmyfaq.de/). But in the end I ended up writing my own FAQ system because I wasn't satisfied with the features.